# Moving from one Activity to another in Android, without creating unecessary Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating an Android application in which the user is required to login. After enering their account details, they will be redirected to another activity called ProfileActivity from LoginActivity. The problem is that when I go from one activity to another using the code shown below, extra activities are created. Why is this a problem? When the user Logs-in they have the ability to logout. Upon logging out, the user can press the go back button on their Android phone to redirect them back to ProfileActivity, regardless of them just loggin out.

Is there a way, to terminate an activity? Relating to the exmaple above, I want to terminate the ProfileActivity as soon as the users logs out.

Here is how i currently move from LoginActivity to ProfileActivity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
```

And here is the opposite:

```
startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
```

I am not sure what other code you may need to help me out, but feel free to ask. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have executed:

```java
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
```

In `LoginActivity` you can also call `finish()` to close that activity.

Comment: Nice and simple, Thanks.